# hack or something similar on my iPad Air

Tags: ipad, facebook, skype

I am new to using an iPad but I clicked accidentally on a bad link in Facebook and since then My Skype has been hacked and sending erroneous messages to my Skype contacts..how do I find out and remove malware on my iPad.  I have tried looking for an antivirus or a way to be able to look on my pad to see where I might be able to see where any malware may be hidden...I.e. On a PC it can be inregistry etc, whereas on an iPad I don't have a clue where to look but I have not been able to find any sufficient answer to help.   This question may be a bit basic for here but I didn't know where else to ask as I wasn't getting any answers elsewhere I.e Apple, Google, etc X

Comment: Change your Skype password and see if it keeps happening.

Comment: As my nexus has not been compromised I will change password on that...have deleted Skype off the iPad for now...will see how it goes x

Comment: I do not understand the yellow banner saying put on hold....I had looked for answers elsewhere but kept getting it saying that it couldn't happen but in my instance it had...but as I am a newbie to the iPad and Apple products I do not know how to solve this problem, so hence why I asked the above. I do not see how it can be worded any differently as I was only stating facts to that which had happened.

Comment: The yellow banner is because we cannot provide you with a definitive solution to your problem because we are not Skype or Apple. You should probably contact either Skype or Apple (most likely Skype) and see what they recommend. We would love to help you, but we can't really do that effectively in this situation. Another thing is that it's *highly* unlikely that your iPhone has been compromised; it's most likely that your Skype account has been compromised - it happens to lots of people.

Comment: But it has only been compromised since I clicked on a link in Facebook and then downloaded Skype onto my iPad....and signed into it on the pad.....since I changed the password on Skype on my nexus the link messages have stopped....so from my logic the problem still lies with my iPad being compromised...Skype will just say change your password...which I have done...but still doesn't solve the originating problem that I clicked on a link that seems to have compromised my iPad...x

Comment: If you still think your post is fine, despite what @Andrew Larsson said, you can make a post over at AskDifferent Meta for a more in-depth explation as of why it was put on hold.

Answer (score 2):

Go to Settings > General > Profiles and Device Management. Delete any profiles you don't remember installing, then restart your iPad.

Next, update it to the latest version of iOS (9.3.2), this should remove the Jailbreak, if there is one, as that version cannot be Jailbroken.

As for what caused it to send spam to your contacts:
If the iPad had malware, well, obviously that was it.
If not, did you sign into it on any other devices?

Also, does your daughter use an iPhone, iPad, or Mac? If so, you can use FaceTime instead of Skype.

Comment: It's is iPad Air tablet...not a phone. It has latest update on it.  I have not modded the tablet in anyway as its only 3 months into a 24 month contract. My daughter has a generic tablet she uses to Skype to me with.  I have Skype on my nexus 7 2013 tablet too but battery was dead at the time which was why I downloaded it to my iPad. I will see if I can do what you suggest above x

Comment: All I can see on profiles in settings is the cloud wifi profiles....I can't upload screenshots to here to show you....

Comment: It's last update was 9.3.2 iOS.....and says its up to date x

Comment: At the moment it seems changing password on Skype on my nexus has worked...so far...but how do I get rid of possible malware on my iPad? X

Comment: @JosieTho iOS malware is VERY, VERY rare. It is more common with a Jailbreak and/or running older versions of iOS, but since you are not Jailbroken and have no unaccounted for profiles, I would say you don't have malware on the iPad. I would point the finger towards your Nexus tablet. Android, by contrast, is known for having a lot of malware, and there's nothing I could tell you about to detect it or get rid of it, but you might find help on another SE site.

Comment: It was on my iPad that I clicked on the link, then needed to download Skype to it...sign in...and then the erroneous messages started...at the time the nexus tablet's battery was dead as it had not been charged for a week as I had primarily been using the iPad...but since changing changing password on nexus...no more erroneous messages being sent..so to me proves it was and possibly still is on the iPad...x